# PHP/MySQL Join Syntax: Comparing Two Columns in Separate Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Learning how to join MySQL tables for my sports league website. This seems like a relatively simple question.  Would greatly appreciate it if someone could help clarify my thought process here:

I have a league schedule page that generates HTML table rows with game info for every game in the "test_league" MySQL table.  One of the HTML columns is intended to display the location for that game by pulling the location data for the home team, which is stored in the "user_schools" table in the same database.

I know exactly what I want to do, I just can't seem to get the syntax quite right.  Here's the code:

```
<?php

// Connect to the database:
require ('../mysqli_connect.php');

// Make the query for games from the schedule database:
$q = "SELECT game_date, game_time, away_team, home_team, home_score, away_score, arbiter_id FROM test_league";
$r = mysqli_query($db, $q);

// Make the query to determine where the games will be played:
$location = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT football_location FROM user_schools WHERE home_team=school_name INNER JOIN test_league");
$map = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT football_map FROM user_schools WHERE home_team=school_name INNER JOIN test_league");

// Declare two variables to help determine the background color of each row:
$i = 0;
$bgcolor = array('row1', 'row2');

// Begin function to print each game as a row:
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    echo '<tr class="' . $bgcolor[$i++ % 2] .'"><td>' . $row['game_date'] . '</td><td>' . $row['game_time'] . '</td><td class="alignleft"><a href="">' . $row['away_team'] . '</a> vs<br><a href="">' . $row['home_team'] . '</a></td>';

    // Determine if the score has been reported:
    if ($row['home_score'] == '0' && $row['away_score'] == '0') {
        echo '<td><a href=""><img src="images/report_icon.png" alt="Report Score" /></a></td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>' . $row['home_score'] . '<br>' . $row['away_score'] . '</td>';
    }

    echo '<td><a href="' . $map . '">' . $location . '</a></td><td><a href="">' . $row['arbiter_id'] . '</a></td></tr>';

}

mysqli_free_result ($r);

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

If clarification is needed, "home_team" is located in "test_league" and "team_name" is located in "user_schools".

I've seen the Venn diagram illustrations for using table joins, but can't quite seem to execute this seemingly straightforward task. Your advice is most welcome!

Comment: Do you have any relation in 'user_schools' table and 'test_league' in common?

Comment: Can you post up the definitions of your tables and the field they have in common?

Comment: @MShahzadKhan - The two tables have no column names in common.  However, the common link is the school name, which can be found in the "school_name" column of "user_schools" as well as the "home_team" column in "test_league".  I want query to grab the location data stored in that school's "user_schools" row to echo in the printed HTML row.

Comment: @StephenO'Flynn - The "user_schools" table is basically the static master table for all of the member schools and includes their user name, password, and game locations for each sport.  The "test_league" table is just a sample game schedule for one individual league with imported data.  The two tables do not have any column names in common.  However, the school name will be identical in the "school_name" column of "user_schools" and "home_team" column in "test_league".  Does that help clarify?

Comment: I indented your `while` block as well. This is important. You run a SELECT at the top to get the information for **all** the teams, but then run two more selects to get what looks like the information for the single team. It wouldn't have worked even if the SQL was correct as it's outside the while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing three separate `SELECT`s in your code, which negates the use of a JOIN. The way you have your code you can get the requisite information without doing a JOIN at all, just use the WHERE. The JOIN allows you to select columns from multiple related tables in a single call. The query to get all the information in one query using the JOIN would look like this:

```
SELECT tl.game_date, tl.game_time, tl.away_team, tl.home_team, tl.home_score,tl.away_score, tl.arbiter_id, us.football_location, us.football_map
FROM test_league tl
    INNER JOIN user_schools us ON (tl.home_team = us.school_name)
ORDER BY tl.game_date, tl.game_time, tl.home_team, tl.away_team;
```

I added table aliases so you can see where the columns are coming from. Notice that the last two columns come from the **user_schools** table and not the main **test_league** table.

---

Your PHP code would then have a change in this line, since you now have all the information in the *$row* variable, you echo that out instead of *$location* and *$map*:

```
echo '<td><a href="' . $row['map'] . '">' . $row['football_location'] . '</a></td><td><a href="">' . $row['arbiter_id'] . '</a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback.  This actually worked like a charm for displaying the correct location and map.  However, it seems to have interfered with the primary index and no longer displays the games sequentially by date, but rather groups them by location.  You can see the page in action here: http://www.parochialathleticleague.org/schedules_test.html

Comment: That's entirely possible. You can add an `ORDER BY` clause to set this up the way you want. I'll edit my answer. You can change the columns and sort order as you see fit.

Comment: You've been a HUGE help.  It works exactly as intended now and you helped clarify a few concepts along the way.  Sincere thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, i didn't execute this source code but review the SQL.

something's seems wrong. try this query.

```
SELECT football_location 
FROM user_schools A
INNER JOIN test_league B
WHERE A.home_team=A.school_name 
;
```

and

```
SELECT football_map 
FROM user_schools A
INNER JOIN test_league B
WHERE A.home_team=A.school_name 
;
```

WHERE must be placed after JOIN. and use alias as A,B to clarify.

Comment: Thanks very much for the input.  I modified the code as per your suggestion, but nothing is displaying (which was the case before).  I'm wondering if I'm using the variables in the echo statement incorrectly?

Comment: @712Jefferson you can try var_dump($row); belows **while()** . hav u seen?

Answer (score 1):

```
select us.football_location from user_schools us left join test_league tl on us.school_name = tl.home_team
```

It will get you all the locations.

If you want any specific then put condition in where clause, forexample.

```
select us.football_location from user_schools us left join test_league tl on us.school_name = tl.home_team where us.id = 'id here'
```

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately, but thank you for attempting to help.  Something about the syntax forces the table to terminate completely.

Comment: If you have a second, can you please clarify what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question, with new code. So i can see on which page you are at the moment. I will then suggest answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this join:

`tl` is alias for `test_league` table and `us` is alias for `user_schools` table.

```
SELECT
    tl.*,
    us.football_location,
    us.football_map
FROM
    test_league tl
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_schools us ON (tl.home_team = us.school_name)
```

I added a demo on `SQL Fiddle`. [**See the results on SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd3a1/1)

```
$q = "SELECT
        tl.*,
        us.football_location,
        us.football_map
    FROM
        test_league tl
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_schools us ON (tl.home_team = us.school_name)";
$r = mysqli_query($db, $q);

$i = 0;
$bgcolor = array('row1', 'row2');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr class="' . $bgcolor[$i++ % 2] .'"><td>' . $row['game_date'] . '</td><td>' . $row['game_time'] . '</td><td class="alignleft"><a href="">' . $row['away_team'] . '</a> vs<br><a href="">' . $row['home_team'] . '</a></td>';
    if ($row['home_score'] == '0' && $row['away_score'] == '0') {
        echo '<td><a href=""><img src="images/report_icon.png" alt="Report Score" /></a></td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td>' . $row['home_score'] . '<br>' . $row['away_score'] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '<td><a href="' . $row['football_map'] . '">' . $row['football_location'] . '</a></td><td><a href="">' . $row['arbiter_id'] . '</a></td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm only confused about one thing.  Can you please clarify what "tl.*" is supposed to represent?

Comment: It's a short name of table. `tl` is alias for `test_league` table and `us` is alias for `user_schools` table. `tl.*` means select all of fields from `test_league` table. You can try by field name too instead of `tl.*`. e.g. `tl.game_date, tl.home_score, ...`